# Wordpress 2 blog show in Magento2 home page?

Tags: magento, magento2, fishpig

I have done fishpig integration  with magento2 succesfully but  i am not able to show 2 blog post Magento2 home page  i created my custom.phtml file and call it to home page but only single post are coming

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance() ?>
<?php $posts = $objectManager->create('FishPig\WordPress\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection')
    ->addPostTypeFilter('post')
    ->setOrderByPostDate()
    ->addIsViewableFilter()
    ->setPageSize(5)
    ->load(2); ?>
<?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>

            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $post->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?></a>
                <?php if ($image = $post->getFeaturedImage()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $post->getUrl() ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $image->getAvailableImage() ?>" src="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?>" />
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <p><?php echo $post->getPostExcerpt(40) ?></p></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to show two latest post

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine, however you don't need to pass the '2' to the load method.

```
->load(2); // You don't need the 2

->load();  // This is fine
```

If this code is returning 1 post maybe it is because you only  have 1 post in your blog?

The code below will show how many posts you have that are published.

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance() ?>
<?php $posts = $objectManager->create('FishPig\WordPress\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection')
  ->addPostTypeFilter('post')
  ->setOrderByPostDate()
  ->addIsViewableFilter()
  ->load(); ?>
<?php echo count(posts) ?> posts
```